How to load efifb when no PCI monitor attached?
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server box running on a AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics GPU.  I boot the server with the nomodeset kernel boot option to avoid a blank screen and to avoid the system hanging on shutdown.  A monitor can be attached using HDMI.
Before upgrading to 22.04, I used to be able to plug in a monitor some time after boot to get the tty login screen.
After upgrading to 22.04, if I boot with the monitor attached, the kernel probes the attached PCI device, creates /sys/devices/platform/efi-framebuffer.0 and a default EFI VGA driver is loaded, the framebuffer is created and I get a text-based command line (tty1).  That makes me happy.
$ sudo fbset -i

mode "1920x1080-77"
    # D: 207.383 MHz, H: 85.273 kHz, V: 77.240 Hz
    geometry 1920 1080 1920 1080 32
    timings 4822 240 32 16 4 240 4
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : EFI VGA
    Address     : 0xd0000000
    Size        : 8294400
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 0
    YPanStep    : 0
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 7680
    Accelerator : No

$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display UNCLAIMED
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
     vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
     version: c9
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcf7ffff
*-graphics
     product: EFI VGA
     physical id: 1
     logical name: /dev/fb0
     capabilities: fb
     configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

In the kernel log I see these messages:
kernel: [    0.310858] pci 0000:08:00.0: BAR 0: assigned to efifb
...
kernel: [    0.384501] efifb: probing for efifb
kernel: [    0.384519] efifb: framebuffer at 0xd0000000, using 8100k, total 8100k
kernel: [    0.384522] efifb: mode is 1920x1080x32, linelength=7680, pages=1
kernel: [    0.384524] efifb: scrolling: redraw
kernel: [    0.384525] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
kernel: [    0.384593] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
kernel: [    0.387527] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device

When the Ubuntu server is not connected to a monitor at boot-time, the kernel creates /sys/devices/platform/platform-framebuffer.0 and there is no /dev/fb0.  lshw shows the unclaimed display device, but no graphics.  When I plug in the monitor later, there is no video signal.  I do not get any of the messages above in the kernel log.
My question: how can I instruct the kernel to load the EFI VGA framebuffer device, whether the monitor is connected or not?  I just want to be able to plug in the monitor without having to reboot the server.
I thought EDID might have been the answer, but I just kept getting a blank screen when a monitor was attached.

I fixed this by upgrading the kernel from 5.15.0-112 to 6.5.0-41.
Once I had done that I could remove nomodeset from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and the amdgpu device driver started up.  I once again had access to the console, whether I started with a monitor attached or not.
